# Find the sum of the numbers on the circle

Tags: code-golf

Consider an \$n \times n\$ grid and a circle of radius \$r \leq \sqrt{2} n\$ with its center in the top left. In each square there is an integer from the range -3 to 3, inclusive.  For a given radius, there is a set of squares in the grid which are not at least half covered by a circle of radius \$r\$ but are at least half covered by a circle of larger radius.  Your task to output the sum of the integers in those squares.

Takes this example:

[image]

The smaller circle has radius \$3.5 \cdot \sqrt{2}\$ and the larger circle has radius \$4.5 \cdot \sqrt{2}\$.  The numbers for squares that are at least half covered by the larger circle but not the smaller one are \$1, -1, 3, 3, 2, -1, -1, 1, -3, -1, 1\$. These sum to \$4\$.

You might be wondering why the \$-1\$ number in square (4,4) is not included.
If we zoom in we can see why. The blue dots are the center of the squares.

[image]

If we had chosen the smaller radius to be \$2.5 \cdot \sqrt{2}\$ and the larger circle has radius \$3.5 \cdot \sqrt{2}\$ then we get the sum of the values we need is \$-1\$.

[image]

Here is the matrix from the examples given:

```
  [[ 3,  0,  1,  3, -1,  1,  1,  3, -2, -1],
   [ 3, -1, -1,  1,  0, -1,  2,  1, -2,  0],
   [ 2,  2, -2,  0,  1, -3,  0, -2,  2,  1],
   [ 0, -3, -3, -1, -1,  3, -2,  0,  0,  3],
   [ 2,  2,  3,  2, -1,  0,  3,  0, -3, -1],
   [ 1, -1,  3,  1, -3,  3, -2,  0, -3,  0],
   [ 2, -2, -2, -3, -2,  1, -2,  0,  0,  3],
   [ 0,  3,  0,  1,  3, -1,  2, -3,  0, -2],
   [ 0, -2,  2,  2,  2, -2,  0,  2,  1,  3],
   [-2, -2,  0, -2, -2,  2,  0,  2,  3,  3]]
```

## Input

A 10 by 10 matrix of integers in the range -3 to 3, inclusive and a radius \$r=\sqrt{2} (a+1/2)\$ where \$a\$ is a non negative integer. The radius input will be the integer \$a\$.

## Output

The sum of the numbers in the squares in the matrix which are not at least half covered by a circle of radius \$r\$ but are at least half covered by a circle of radius \$r + \sqrt{2}\$.

These are the outputs for some different values of \$a\$ using the example matrix.

```
a = 0 gives output 6  ( 0 + 3 + 3)
a = 1 gives output 3  (1 + -1 + -1 + 2 + 2)
a = 2 gives output -1 (3 + -1 + 1 + 0 + -2 + -3 + -3 + +0 + 2 + 2)
a = 3 gives output 4  (1 + -1 + -3 + 1 + -1 + -1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + -1 + 1)
```

## Accuracy

Your answer should be exactly correct.  The question of which squares to include can be resolved exactly mathematically.

Comment: Is d guaranteed to be an integer, or can it be any real number? Also, what is the margin of error? is it acceptable to incorrectly include a square with 49% or 51%? That will make a huge difference to the length of the code. It would be much easier if we could include all squares that have *any* part of the circle in them.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I have made the input clear I hope. I'll add a comment about numerical accuracy m

Comment: Is there counterexample where [midpoint included] xor [half in]?

Comment: I mean circle cover midpoint but not half covered

Comment: @l4m2 If the circle goes directly though the midpoint and it is one of the squares at location (i, i) (that is on the diagonal) then the square is not half covered. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No but I stop here and ask ChatGPT instead

Comment: Is this not a symmetrical problem about the diagonal of the grid. If so should there not be 10 qualifying squares in your first example viz. 1, -1, 3, 3, 2, -1, 1, -3, -1, 1 giving a total of 5

Comment: @Graham Thank you. Fixed

Comment: I think 'd' and 'x' are confusing names. Use 'r' for the radius, and maybe 'a' for 'x'.

Comment: @user1502040 Thanks, fixed. Could you double check my second example please.

Comment: Following my previous comment about symmetry and given your explanation why square 4,4 should not be included should square 3,3 on the grid diagonal be included to give us 11 squares with the answer dropping back to 4

Comment: @Graham Yes. Fixed again. The second example should be correct now too.

Comment: The result for a=0 should be 6; the 0.5 diameter circle only fills about 39% of the top-left grid square

Comment: @NickKennedy Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
ŒJ_.²§<Ɱ+.+Ø.²ḤƲ}^/ḋF{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#%23y0rNyan8///oJK94vUObDi23ebRxnbae9uEZQN7DHUuObaqN03@4o9ut@v@jxp3WjxrmKOjaKTxqmKtifXg51@HlQNVHd9dG/v8fHa1grKOgYADEhkAMZOsaQtkwvhFILFaHS0FBIRqmAK7IAMo2gvBBihUMYIqNIBIQQagCqG26RjBNMMUGEEldZBuMkTSDsDGayWC3G0EVG0D5MIPgJiOZBncCkskQJyGZrAvDMEWGuJyBZCVK8BkhexTZgzB3o4eMEcwAqGJdJEk4G1kx2A@xsf8tAQ)

A dyadic link taking a 10x10 integer matrix as its first argument and an integer as its second argument and returning an integer. Doesn’t use any fractions other than halves and quarters so should not lose anything to floating point accuracy.

Uses the same methodology as [@Ajax1234’s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268577/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too!

### Explanation

```
ŒJ_.²§<Ɱ+.+Ø.²ḤƲ}^/ḋF{­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ŒJ                      # ‎⁡Indices along matrix
  _.                    # ‎⁢Subtract 0.5
    ²                   # ‎⁣Square
     §                  # ‎⁤Sum inner lists
      <Ɱ       Ʋ}       # ‎⁢⁡Less than each of the following applied to the right argument as a monad:
        +.              # ‎⁢⁢Add 0.5
          +Ø.           # ‎⁢⁣Add zero and one
             ²          # ‎⁢⁤Square
              Ḥ         # ‎⁣⁡Double
                 ^/     # ‎⁣⁢Reduce using xor
                   ḋF{  # ‎⁣⁣Dot product with the flattened matrix
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

### Alternative approach [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```
+1.,.²Ḥµæ._²}½÷@ÆṬ,×ʋʋ¥Ɱ⁵ŻHI+.ḞḞRŒṪfU$)ḟ/œị⁹S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/bUE9H79CmhzuWHNp6eJle/KFNtYf2Ht7ucLjt4c41Ooenn@o@1X1o6aON6x41bj2628NTW@/hjnlAFHR00sOdq9JCVTQf7pivf3Tyw93djxp3Bv8/uvvw8kdNa/7/t/yvoBAdrWCso6BgAMSGQAxk6xpC2TC@EUgsVodLAagapgCuyADKNoLwQYoVDGCKjSASEEGoAqhtukYwTTDFBhBJXWQbjJE0g7AxmslgtxtBFRtA@TCD4CYjmQZ3ApLJECchmawLwzBFhricgWQlSvAZIXsU2YMwd6OHjBHMAKhiXSRJOBtZMdgPsbEA)

This is a dyadic link that takes the integer a as its first argument and the 10x10 matrix as its second and returns an integer. This uses the integral of the circle equation to calculate the area in each column. This is useful on the left hand part of the quarter circle but not on the right when it’s harder to calculate which squares are partially filled. My code therefore uses symmetry to control for this. There could be floating point error, but it’s not apparent in the example used here.

The formula used for the integral of \$\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\$ is:

\$\frac{1}{2} (x \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} + r^2 \arctan{\frac{x}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}})\$

This was generated using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%E2%88%9A%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29).

### Explanation

```
+1.,.²Ḥµæ._²}½÷@ÆṬ,×ʋʋ¥Ɱ⁵ŻHI+.ḞḞRŒṪfU$)ḟ/œị⁹S­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
+1.,.                                          # ‎⁡Add [1.5, 0.5]
     ²                                         # ‎⁢Squared
      Ḥ                                        # ‎⁣Doubled
       µ                              )        # ‎⁤For each of these squared radii:
                      ¥Ɱ⁵                      # ‎⁢⁡- Following as a dyad using the squared radius as the left argument and each integer from 1 to 10 inclusive as the right (referred to as x below)
        æ.           ʋ                         # ‎⁢⁢  - Dot product of [the squared radius, 1] with the result of the following:
          _²}                                  # ‎⁢⁣    - Subtract x squared from the squared radius
             ½                                 # ‎⁢⁤    - Square root
                    ʋ                          # ‎⁣⁡    - Following as a dyad using the above as the left argument (called z below) and x as the right argument
              ÷@                               # ‎⁣⁢      - Divide x by z
                ÆṬ                             # ‎⁣⁣      - Arctan
                  ,×                           # ‎⁣⁤      - Paired with z multiplied by x
                         Ż                     # ‎⁤⁡- Prepend zero
                          H                    # ‎⁤⁢- Half
                           I                   # ‎⁤⁣- Increments
                            +.                 # ‎⁤⁤- Add 0.5
                              Ḟ                # ‎⁢⁡⁡- Real part of complex values; floor real values
                               Ḟ               # ‎⁢⁡⁢- Floor the real values generated from the complex values above
                                R              # ‎⁢⁡⁣- Range from 1 to each of these
                                 ŒṪ            # ‎⁢⁡⁤- Two-dimensional indices of truthy values
                                   fU$         # ‎⁢⁢⁡- Keep only those which also exist in their reversed form
                                       ḟ/      # ‎⁢⁢⁢Remove the squares captured by the smaller circle from those captured by the larger one
                                         œị⁹   # ‎⁢⁢⁣Multidimensional index into the matrix
                                            S  # ‎⁢⁢⁤Sum
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: +1 for using the correct integral formula. I was concerned when OP insisted on accuracy that answers would appear that didn't! An alternative to using the formula would be the following algorithm: (1) find the points where the circle cuts the square (2) calculate the area of the sector bounded by the circle perimeter and 2 lines to the origin (3) subtract the triangular areas not contained within the square. Step 2 clearly requires some kind of inverse trig operation, no matter how you do it.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt good spot - I just put the closing parenthesis in the wrong place. The formula in the code doesn’t have that problem though!

Comment: Very glad to see an integration based solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Python3, 105 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
f=lambda m,d:sum(v for x,r in E(m)for y,v in E(r)if(U:=x*x+x+y*y+y+1)>d*d*2 and U<(d+1)**2*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBboMwDD2Pr/AxCWGCsEkTGr31E3pCHJgCa6QlRSmt4OsZaWKUVdrBkp/9/PzscZnOF1N@jHZdj3Vvbrq33dQnQ/3T6S/Zgeayut40ucNwsTBzC8rAkWjq4MLvHlqqBnKq6pnN6ZwubEmXtKAHySQT0BkJp08itwpjggm6ulnlJm1nvnvyRqvkZbTKTGQgTQMlB8i3KLbY8qwIOWLhai1PAKBBwk7KQy48dmTIkSx8wxcDIWzLBA4hOffNLN5QRsMuyiflh3cRyHnAKLQrR2q7hUjZW4qUMwwkFf/ZiFb@eZ@ID40PRN/PnxEoEMhZ1NzzmPy4oW25Sl/fKV1/AQ)

Comment: What answer are you getting for my second example?

Comment: `d<dist((.5,.5),(-x,-y))<=d+2**.5`. Although there should be a way of avoiding `dist`.

Comment: The square (3,0) should be included. The area covered is approx 0.51223.

Comment: The second example should be 3, -1, 1, 0, -2, 0,  -3, -3, 2, 2

Comment: @Simd Thanks for the clarification, updated

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: https://tio.run/#%23dVDBboMwDD2Pr/AxCWGCsEkTGr31E3pCHJgCa6QlRSmt4OsZaWKUVdrBkp/9/PzscZnOF1N@jHZdj3Vvbrq33dQnQ/3T6S/Zgeayut40ucNwsTBzC8rAkWjq4MLvHlqqBnKq6pnN6ZwubEmXtKAHySQT0BkJp08itwpjggm6ulnlJm1nvnvyRqvkZbTKTGQgTQMlB8i3KLbY8qwIOWLhai1PAKBBwk7KQy48dmTIkSx8wxcDIWzLBA4hOffNLN5QRsMuyiflh3cRyHnAKLQrR2q7hUjZW4qUMwwkFf/ZiFb@eZ@ID40PRN/PnxEoEMhZ1NzzmPy4oW25Sl/fKV1/AQ is shorter and avoids floating point error. Technically it should be `+0.5` at the end of where U is defined and then an`>=`, but with the way the question is set, `+1` and `>` work fine.

Comment: @NickKennedy Thank you very much! Updated

Comment: @Ajax1234 -2 bytes Python, 103 bytes: [`lambda m,d,E=enumerate:sum(v for x,r in E(m)for y,v in E(r)if(U:=x*x+x+y*y+y+1)>d*d*2 and U<(d+1)**2*2)`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVFLTsMwEBVLeopZ-osSB6QqIux6hK5CFkFOSqTGrUxSJWdhEwnBnWDJSYhrO3IrsRh53szzmzf2-9dx7F4Pavqos-fPvqv5-nu3L9sXWULLJNtklerbSpddlb71LTpBfdAwMA2Ngg1qsYEjO1mocVOjbZoNZKADHclIRxrjJ0kkEVAqCdtHJOcKIYIIbMf93PwajcYo6FLtKnSP09XtUTeqQzXKc0gYQDRHPMec89jlHgtTK9gKAHJPWEiRy4XFhgyRJwvbsEVHcNO48Jc8ObJNHk5Igssmkivls3fhyJHDXmhRDtQWC4GytRQocx-eFP9nIxh58XwiXDRc0Pu-fhnhBRyZB80lD8nnHYqCNfTuAbuvniZ7_gE)

Comment: @solid.py `d*d*2<x*x+x+y*y+y+1<(d+1)**2*2`.

Comment: You can save a byte between `2` and `and`

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 104 bytes

```
=sum(makearray(10,10,lambda(x,y,isbetween(((x-0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2)^0.5,K4,K4+2^0.5,1,)*index(A1:J10,x,y))))
```

Put the matrix in cells `A1:J10`, the integer \$a\$ in cell `K4`, the formula for \$r\$ `=2 ^ 0.5 * (K2 + 0.5)` in cell `K4` and the formula in cell `K7`.

[image: sum circle]

The input is the matrix `A1:J10` and the value \$r\$ in `K4`. Uses the same approximation as the Python and Jelly answers.